# Phonegap / Cordova Youtube embed videos on iOS not working

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, youtube

I  am trying to embed Youtube Videos to my IOS Cordova project .. its not showing the videos on IPads and Iphones.
this my code

```
<iframe width="100%" height="221.02"
  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/uFyaDBmvR8c?showinfo=0&frameborder=0&allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and I added the whitelist plugin:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" spec="*"/>
```

And then white listed https access to Youtube:

```
<allow-navigation href="https://*youtube.com/*"/>
```

in the config.xml file.
And it's working now.

Comment: this fixed video play, but video thumbnail in <img> tag still not loading thumbnail images from youtube link

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this.

```
<iframe width="100%" height="221.02" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/uFyaDBmvR8c?showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

To this.

```
 <iframe style="width:100%; height:221px;" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/uFyaDBmvR8c?showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```